# Pagination <a> tag click slenium not loading but normal driver.get(pagination_link) works?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to click on pagination link but my request is getting blocked but when i use that pagination link directly with `driver.get("justdial.com/Delhi/Grocery-Stores/page-2")` it works , can u tell what is the problem why is click pagination not working am i missing some headers or what , thanks for your patience

Here is how i open the browser and the link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
 
# driver.get method() will navigate to a page given by the URL address
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Grocery-Stores")
# my logic here sleep , scrape , etc and at end click on pagination link
driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_count)).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(PAGE_PAUSE_TIME)
```

Yeah this clicks right element and link but the page says some error occured but the same page works well on my normal browser

Answer (score 1):

The next page located out of the visible screen view.
So you have to scroll to it in order to click it.
But there is additional difficulty with this specific site.
When you scrolling down it loads additional elements so the next page button will again be out of the visible screen.
You can overcome this issue in several ways.
The first is not recommended but is more simple.
You can click on the next page element with JavaScript executor as following:

```
next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[rel=next]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
```

The more complex way is to scroll the page until the next page element becomes visible and then click it.
Something like this:

```
next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[rel=next]")
while not next_page.is_displayed():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)
next_page.click()
```

Comment: so what u mean to say is that the pagination links need to be visible then only will it work , but if i manually scroll and then click then also it does not work and it also not work if i directly enter pagination url directly in testing browser , it only works when i use driver.get(pagination_url) or when i open it in normal browser

Comment: In order to click element with Selenium the element should be visible, clickable, not covered with other element etc. Selenium imitates real user UI actions. So, as a user you can't click element that is out of the screen, you have to scroll to it. And if more elements loaded - scroll again.

Comment: And as a user you can navigate to some url, but this is not done by clicking on next page element in this case

Comment: i am able to click the pagination link and it loads correct url i already mentioned in my question my question is that this page is not loading , i ve solved scrolling etc , quoting from my question just incase u missed -----"""Yeah this clicks right element and link but the page says some error occured but the same page works well on my normal browser""""

Comment: Maybe the pop-up appearing during the scrolling blocks you?

Comment: Do you have a logic to close this element? Located by xpath `//*[@id='best_deal_div']//span[contains(@onclick,'closePopUp')]`

Comment: Hello @prophet nothing is blocking me clicking that link i click that link then page starts loading for that link now this link is not opening and server is throwing oops some error occured

Comment: I guess it is not working since the element is still not really ready to be clicked.  Real user will not do this action... So, as I see this flow:As I already wrote: page should be fully loaded and then scrolled with pauses to let the new items loaded and only after several scrolls, when the page is really scrolled to it bottom the element should be clicked. You should imitate real user actions, not to try do something what a normal user can't do via GUI

Comment: can you try entering that url normally in your testing browser like go to next tab and enter `justdial.com/Delhi/Grocery-Stores/page-2` and see what happens

Comment: putting this URL directly opens the page correctly

Comment: in my case it is not opening when i go to next tab and enter this url but opens only with driver.get(url) , i am sharing screen shot

Comment: Maybe it will be better if you share all your code in the question?